# Field and Form Validation with ember.js

Tags: forms, validation, ember.js

I've integrated [Boronine's](http://boronine.com/) excellent field validation code for ember.js from [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kTJCH/).  While that is wonderful, I still need to perform form level validation, to ensure that when the user submits the form, everything is okay.

What's the best way to do that?  Is there a way that I can mark a field as having been validated, so that the form handler can simply walk the fields to see what has been validated or not?

```
MP.SignUpFormView = Em.View.extend({
    submitLogin:function (event) {
        // walk through object fields to perform validation here, but how?!
    }
});
```

Edit:

For clarity, I *am* using Handlebars and binding, not trying to walk DOM objects or the like.

Comment: After a thread with @TrekGlowacki, I've selected [ember validations](https://github.com/lcoq/ember-validations) as my validation framework, for now.  Hopefully it gets baked into ember itself shortly.

Answer (score 5):

The pattern you're trying to use makes sense in applications that follow a document-scripting pattern, which Ember does not. You *can* force this work, but you'll find each next step in the application will get harder and harder.

In Ember display is backed by data objects so form fields in an Ember application are bound to a property on some object and as changes are made, the values are updated immediately. You don't even really need a `<form>` except maybe for styling.

When a user wants to take some action on this object (like persisting it to a server) the application's current state will answer the question "what happens when a user wants to take this action right now?" A user clicking a button here doesn't mean "now serialize the data in the form and do something" it means "I'm done changing the properties of this object and would like to do something else in the application now."

Your handlebars template would look something like this:

```
{{view Ember.Textfield valueBinding="name"}}
{{view Ember.Textfield valueBinding="age"}}

<button {{action save content}}>Save</button>
```

And a possible state in your application where this can be handled

```
Ember.Route.extend({
  save: function(router, event){
    if (event.context.validate()){
      router.transitionTo('someNewState')
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I don't see any particular difference between my question and the pattern you have described - at some level, when the an action needs to happen, the content in the object has to be validated.  I have it in the view, you have it in the route, but it is still there.  However, you have 'event.context.validate' - is that the secret sauce?  If so, that is the part I'm looking for, and am curious as to how that would work.

Comment: `// walk through fields to perform validation here, but how?!` implies you're not validating an object though. You're trying to validated a value on a HTML element. This isn't the kind of logic Ember views are used for.

Comment: True, should have said `// walk through object fields to perform validation`, but the problem remains: a user has filled out a form, the bindings have done their magic and the object is populated, they then submit a form.  I now have to validate the fields in the object, again AND have to validate any form-level items (validating that password and the confirmation password match, for example).  There doesn't seem to be any mechanism built in to ember to handle this.

Comment: You'd only validate objects. Password and password confirmation would be both be model properties. Validations are a WIP and not on ember-data's master yet.

Comment: So... Until then, I roll my own validation in the action handler?  Manually validate object fields again?

Comment: There are several object validation libraries out there. I've used https://github.com/lcoq/ember-validations

Comment: If you can edit your answer to include this, I'll mark it as answered and upvote.